# What is the difference between Json.parse(), Json.toJson(), and Json.stringify() in Scala?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

When using the `play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}` module in Scala, what is the difference between Json.parse(), Json.toJson(), and Json.stringify()?

Answer (score 5):

`Json.parse` - parses a JSON string or InputStream into a JSON tree (AST).

`Json.toJson` - converts any writeable value to a JsValue, i.e. any Scala Class to JSON tree (AST). Implicit Writer is required.

`Json.stringify` - is used to convert a JsValue to a String of JSON.